# Copy a class to another?

Tags: c#, .net, class, copy

I have

```
class A
{
    public int a;
    public string b;
}
```

How can i copy A to another A? In C++ i know i could do `*a1 = *a2;`. Is there something similar in C#? I know i could write a generic solution using reflection but i hope something exist already.

I'm considering changing A to a nullable struct.

Step 2 i'll need to do

```
class B : A {}
class C : A {}
```

and copy the base data from B to C.

Comment: You already asked this here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067725/best-way-to-convert-a-shared-base

Comment: @yodaj007:  This one cleans up his idea from that question.  I've already voted to close the old one.

Comment: It's been awhile since I've coded in C++.  Your example only ensures that both `a1` and `a2` point to the same object in memory so changes in one are reflected in both, right?  So it's not really copying to another `A`, right?

Comment: nope. The *obj = is different from obj=. obj = changes the pointer while *obj copies.

Comment: I had a similar sort of issue myself recently and came up with a generic method - it does use reflection: http://pmichaels.net/2016/03/04/dynamically-copy-a-class-from-one-instance-to-another-using-reflection/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is some simple code that works on any class, not just base.

```
    public static void DuckCopyShallow(this Object dst, object src)
    {
        var srcT = src.GetType();
        var dstT= dst.GetType();
        foreach(var f in srcT.GetFields())
        {
            var dstF = dstT.GetField(f.Name);
            if (dstF == null || dstF.IsLiteral)
                continue;
            dstF.SetValue(dst, f.GetValue(src));
        }

        foreach (var f in srcT.GetProperties())
        {
            var dstF = dstT.GetProperty(f.Name);
            if (dstF == null)
                continue;
            
            dstF.SetValue(dst, f.GetValue(src, null), null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

I have used binary serialization. Basically, serialize the instance to a memory stream. Then, deserialize it out of the memory stream. You will have an exact binary copy. It will be a deep copy, rather than a shallow copy.

```
class a = new ClassA();

class b = MySerializationMethod(a);
```

For a shallow copy you can use `Object.MemberwiseClone`

Comment: +1 for this method.  We've used this many times and it works great.

Comment: It looks like Object.MemberwiseClone only works with the two classes are the same and within the class method? How might i program MySerializationMethod? It seems i'll be using reflection.

Comment: someone posted it below: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sd_surajit/cloning05032007012620AM/cloning.aspx

no reflection needed

Answer (score 5):

Assuming A is just a simple class, you can do

```
A newA = instanceOfA.MemberwiseClone();
```

MemberwiseClone() is a shallow copy though, so if your class gets complex, with properties that are also reference types, this will not work for you.

Comment: Although this cannot be as fast as a non-reflection approach.

Comment: Agreed.  It can be more convenient and scalable than a custom approach however.

Answer (score 4):

there is the `ICloneable` interface which offers up a `Clone()` method.

[Clone on msdn.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what somebody has already done...

[Deep Copy in C# (Cloning for a user defined class)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sd_surajit/cloning05032007012620AM/cloning.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Add the appropriate constructors:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(int a, string b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public Foo(Foo other)
    {
        A = other.A;
        B = other.B;
    }

    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

You should also consider making it immutable, especially if you are considering making it into a struct. Mutable structs are evil.

Finally when you are inheriting from a class you don't need to copy the members from the base class into the subclass.

Comment: +1 if I had enough votes today. Immutable would imply no set properties, right?

Comment: @lpthnc: `private set` would do it.

Comment: Thanks. How would you declare that if you want to keep get as public - on the same line or separately?

Comment: @Ipthnc: public int A { get; private set; }

Answer (score 2):

We've used this code successfully:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Utility {
    internal static class ObjectCloner {
        public static T Clone<T>(T obj) {
            using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream()) {
                BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(buffer, obj);
                buffer.Position = 0;
                T temp = (T)formatter.Deserialize(buffer);
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There may be other methods which work better, but perhaps this will help you

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can Clone, you can define a copy constructor. Why change class to struct just because in C++ you can do something in 10 characters. C# is different. Structs have advantages and disadvantages.